# Change JavaScript text spacing formatting in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, jslint

Is there any way to tweak some of the spacing settings for JScript that aren't explicitly spelled out in Options:Text Editor:JScript:Formatting?

I like having I like having my JavaScript code pass JSLint on "The Good Parts". I also enjoy doing JS in Visual Studio 2010. Unfortunately, I cannot seem to keep the auto-formatting in Visual Studio from breaking one of the JSLint rules when it shuffles things around.

If I write a self-executing function in a JS file that passes JSLint (for extending jQuery, in this case), and then have Visual Studio format it (either automatically or via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>), Visual Studio inserts a space between the closing `}` and the `(jQuery)` parameter.

```
(function ($) {
  // ...
}(jQuery));
```

becomes...

```
(function ($) {
  // ...
} (jQuery));
```

After the auto-format, JSLint gets upset at the last line:

> Problem at line X character Y: Unexpected space between '}' and '('.

Comment: Do you definately want to do this in visual studio? Or would you be prepared to tweak the JSLint settings?

Comment: It would definitely be my preference, but I am guessing I will just have to opt out of "The Good Parts" on that one. It seems like the formatting options for JS are really limited, though.

Comment: I would argue that a relaxation of the strict formatting requirements of JSLint does not detract significantly from "The Good Parts". This is an opinion shared by the creators of JSHint - a community driven fork of JSHint.

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 JS formatting doesn't work when code is wrapped in a self executing function. I'm suffering this too.